# Standalone Client and Spring Web Socket Server

Tags: spring, server

```
package springwebsocketclient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.Transport;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.frame.SockJsMessageCodec;

/**
 *
 * @author Anurag
 */
public class SimpleSpringWebSocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StandardWebSocketClient standardWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketTransport socketTransport = new WebSocketTransport(standardWebSocketClient);
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
        transports.add(socketTransport);
        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        sockJsClient.setMessageCodec(new SockJsMessageCodec() {
            @Override
            public String encode(String... messages) {
                System.out.println("inside encode");
                return "";

            }

            @Override
            public String[] decode(String content) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("inside decode");
                return new String[10];
            }

            @Override
            public String[] decodeInputStream(InputStream content) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("inside decodeInputStream");
                return new String[10];
            }
        });
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        String host = "192.168.3.202";
        int port = 8080;
        String stompUrl = "ws://" + host + ":" + port + "/hello";
        WebSocketHttpHeaders webSocketHttpHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders(new HttpHeaders());
        LocalStompSessionHandler handler = new LocalStompSessionHandler();
        StompHeaders stompHeaders = new StompHeaders();
        try {
            //stompClient.connect(stompUrl, new LocalStompSessionHandler());
            stompClient.connect(stompUrl, handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stompClient.setAutoStartup(true);
    }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package springwebsocketclient;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompFrameHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author Anurag
 */
public class LocalStompSessionHandler implements StompSessionHandler{

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        System.out.println("connectedHeaders = " + connectedHeaders);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {

    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


}


Server Implementation
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            System.out.println("control come here");
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }

package hello;

public class HelloMessage {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

package hello;

import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}

package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private String content;

    public Greeting(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}

package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When i am trying to connect Client to Server Getting this exception:

> May 18, 2016 6:14:15 PM org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.DefaultTransportRequest$ConnectCallback
>   handleFailure
>   SEVERE: No more fallback transports after TransportRequest[url=ws://192.168.3.202:8080/hello/80/6af5b9dd5e0c4fd0be3daee63b74af0b/websocket]
>       javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:636)
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:673)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:826)
>         at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:496)
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:348)
>         at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:152)
>         at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 403.
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:419)
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:343)
>         at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:313)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>         ... 1 more

API versions are:

```
Spring 4.2.5
apache-loggings 1.1.1
J2EE 7
J2SE 8
Jackson-all 1.9
jacksone-core 2.2.3
tyrus-standalone-client 1.12
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no CORS origin header defined, so it's throwing 403 error.
When you enable debug log of Spring Framework web socket it will display following error:

> OriginHandshakeInterceptor - Handshake request rejected, Origin header
>   value 192.168.3.202:8080 not allowed

Add setAllowedOrigins("*") or setAllowedOrigins("http://192.168.3.202:8080") to your endpoint and it will work fine.

```
registry.addEndpoint("/hello").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
```